# Why not just use object(map) for adjacency list edges representation? If instead we use array, we need to do extra linear find operation, isn't it?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

How I see it from articles, they suggest to implement an adjacency list like this:

```
const adjacencyList = new Map()

// add vertex
adjacencyList.set(nodeLabel, [])

// add edge
adjacencyList.get(nodeLabel).push(edgeDestinationNodeLabel)

// remove edge
adjacencyList.get(nodeLabel).forEach(destLabel => /*... if match, remove */)
```

and seeing this I'm wondering, how would you, say, remove edge from such list? Only option I can see - iterate through `adjacencyList.get(nodeLabel)` array and delete the match.

What I haven't found, is an example of an implementation that I have in mind:

```
const adjacencyList = new Map()

// add vertex
adjacencyList.set(nodeLabel, Map())

// add edge
adjacencyList.get(nodeLabel).set(edgeDestinationNodeLabel, true)

// remove edge
adjacencyList.get(nodeLabel).delete(edgeDestinationNodeLabel)
```

Isn't that faster, with the same amount of memory usage, because we are avoiding linear `find` operation?

Also, the second option feels more scalable, as instead of `true` we could store any reference.

Comment: The list uses much less memory and allows faster iteration, which is usually a lot more important than delete.

Comment: ...But, you know, it's important that you don't think of this as a "best practice" or anything like that.  Use whatever works best for the algorithm you're implementing, and don't expect to make the same choice every time.  Know the costs of the various choices so you can make that decision properly every time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, thank you for the response. And speaking about your first comment, how do you evaluate the amount of memory? As I see this: Array is some class in JS, and Map is some class in JS, they both have some methods, so why one of them could possibly use more memory? (Assume that we are talking only about the case when Map's keys are primitives)

Comment: An array stores its items in a resizeable array like `ArrayList` in Java, which will cost about 16 bytes per entry overhead.  A map stores its items in a hash table, like a `HashMap` in Java, which will cost ~8 bytes for the table slot + ~32 bytes for an entry node.  That's more than twice as much, although we haven't counted the key objects in either place.

Comment: It is interesting. Do you think they have the same allocation in JavaScript?

Comment: Close enough.  You should try it -- start node and put 10M entries in a Map and see how the process size changes.  Then do the same for an array

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), not an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

You are right that it is faster to insert and delete edges with this structure. Regarding the memory size, a matrix row might either store an indexed boolean for every node in the graph, or use a `Set` representation containing linked nodes (like you did), and it depends a lot on how sparse the graph is for which one is better. The `Set` approach is similar to an adjacency list, but usually with some overhead to allow efficient search and update.

The main advantage of an adjacency list is its simplicity. It still does well in sparse graphs where a node is linked to only a few others, both in memory size and speed. And in many graph algorithms, the graph isn't updated that often, queries that iterate neighbors of a specific node are much more common - which an adjacency list trivially supports.

Comment: thank you for the response. How then an adjacency list should look like? (I'm getting reverse information to your response in my review on StackExchange https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226926/representation-graph-as-adjacency-list-in-javascript/226992?noredirect=1#comment441526_226992 )

Comment: @Undefitied I don't see conflicting information. What you have there as your `edges` array (with from-to tuples) is just an edge list. An adjacency list does hold the neighbor nodes for each node, an adjacency matrix holds a boolean "has edge" for each possible neighbor for each node. Usually this is really implemented as a non-sparse matrix. A `Map` or `Set` to hold the neighbor information for each node is something in-between.

Comment: The part I see as conflicting is that you describe code above, from the question, as an adjacency matrix, and the guy from StackExchange says, that adjacency list should look like: `edges: { '0': { '1': 1, '4': 1 }, '1': { '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 1 } }`. Do you think both these structures, from this question, and object I've just pasted, are basically the same and the only difference is data type, Map vs Object?

Comment: @Undefitied Yes, it doesn't make a difference whether you use a `Map` or a plain object as a dictionary here.

Comment: Then here is a piece of conflicting information - here you say it is Adjacency Matrix, but there the guy calls it Adjacency List. Summarizing, can I say now, mostly using your's first comment in this thread, that if data structure doesn't have information about a neighbour, then is it is the List, otherwise, it is the Matrix (no matter sparse or non-sparse)?

Comment: @Undefitied The information stored in the structures is the same. The difference is the one that you describe in your question: a list requires linear traversal to find a neighbor, a matrix allows direct lookup.